# Elasticsearch - How to Reindex using NEST 7.1 SDK

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, aws-elasticsearch

I am upgrading my NEST version from 6.8 to 7.1. Since it is major version upgrade, I am experiencing some breaking changes.

One of the breaking change is with Reindex API. Earlier in NEST 6.8, I used to reindex like this:

```
var req = new JObject
{
    { "source", new JObject
        {
            { "index", "sourceIndexName" }
        }
    },
    { "dest", new JObject
        {
            { "index", "destIndexName" }
        }
    }
};
var postDataRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonReindexReq, defaultJsonSerializerSettings);
var response = await elasticSearchClient.LowLevel.ReindexAsync<StringResponse>(postDataRequest, null, cancellationToken);
```

How would I be able to do it now using NEST 7.1?

I see there are 14 different flavors of reindex apis present in the new SDK, but I am not able to find any example online.

Answer (score 2):

There is several constructors, you could have cancellationToken or some other stuff.

The query should be:

```
   var reindexResponse = client.ReindexOnServer(r => r 
                .Source(sou => sou.Index("sourceindex"))
                .Destination(des => des.Index("destindex"))
                .WaitForCompletion(true)
                );
```